# TYPO3 Extbase individual code on backend-deletion of an object

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to execute some individual code when one of my Extbase domain objects is deleted from the list view in TYPO3 backend.

Thought that it could / would work by overwriting the `remove( $o )` method in the according repository like

```
 public function remove( $object ) {
    parent::__remove( $object );
    do_something_i_want();
}
```

, but that won't work I guess. Looks like the repository-methods are only called / used by actions of my extension (e.g. if I had some delete-action in a FE- or BE-plugin) but not when the object is just deleted from list view in the backend? I don't use (up to now) any FE/BE-plugin / -actions - only the simple add/edit/delete functions in the backends list view of my storage folder.

Background: I have e.g. two models with some 1:n relation (let's say `singer` and `song`), where one object includes some uploaded file (`album_cover` > pointing to the file's URL in `/uploads/myext/` folder); using `@cascade` works fine for deleting every `song` belonging to a `singer` that is deleted, but it won't touch the file uploaded (only) for `song.album_cover` - leading to quite some waste over time. So I would love to do some sort of `onDeletionOfSinger() { deleteAllFilesForHisSongs(); }`-thing.
(Same thing would apply on deletion of let's say a single `song` and it's `album_cover`-file.)

Sounds quite easy & common, but I just don't get behind it and found nothing useful - would love some hint / pointing to the right direction :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List view uses TCEmain hooks during its operations, so you can use one of them to intersect  delete action, i.e.: [`processCmdmap_deleteAction`](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_version_1_1_hook_1_1_data_handler_hook.html#a6404324c7088c3c17a9f197e0ce30fa2)

1. Register your hooks class in `typo3conf/ext/your_ext/ext_tables.php`

   ```
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][] = 'VENDORNAME\\YourExt\\Hooks\\ProcessCmdmap';
   ```
2. Create a class with valid namespace and path (according to previous step)
   file: `typo3conf/ext/your_ext/Classes/Hooks/ProcessCmdmap.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace VENDORNAME\YourExt\Hooks;

   class ProcessCmdmap {
      /**
       * hook that is called when an element shall get deleted
       *
       * @param string $table the table of the record
       * @param integer $id the ID of the record
       * @param array $record The accordant database record
       * @param boolean $recordWasDeleted can be set so that other hooks or
       * @param DataHandler $tcemainObj reference to the main tcemain object
       * @return   void
       */
       function processCmdmap_postProcess($command, $table, $id, $value, $dataHandler) {
           if ($command == 'delete' && $table == 'tx_yourext_domain_model_something') {
               // Perform something before real delete
               // You don't need to delete the record here it will be deleted by CMD after the hook
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to clear system cache after registering new hook's class

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the nice hint - works very well. Just took me a while to get behind the Doc-params record/recordWasDeleted suppose not to fit the real parameters while looking for the right way to get the desired filename/value from the record to be further processed (deletion of an image e.g.) ;-). But using `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getRecord('my_table', $id, 'field_or_fields_needed', '', false)` seems to work fine. And - maybe you want to edit for others: when the thing is called the record is already set to "del" so no need of own delete code as suggested.

Comment: Just for the ones with similar scenarios: the hook does not "apply" to cascaded deletes (in my example e.g. the deletion of songs when an artist is deleted) so you have to keep the related childs in mind from parent view (when delete action is performed on `parent_table`, as delete on `child_table` check only applies when the child is deleted in the backend, not in case of cascaded deletion, if anything has to happen on their deletion.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to biesiors answer I want to point out, that there is also a signalSlot for this. So you can  rather register on that signal than hooking into tcemain.

in your `ext_localconf.php` put:

```
$signalSlotDispatcher =
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\SignalSlot\\Dispatcher');
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Backend',
    'afterRemoveObject',
    'Vendor\MxExtension\Slots\MyAfterRemoveObjectSlot',
    'myAfterRemoveObjectMethod'
);
```

So in your Slot you have this PHP file:

```
namespace Vendor\MxExtension\Slots;
class MyAfterRemoveObjectSlot {
    public function myAfterRemoveObjectMethod($object) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Note thet `$object` will be the $object that was just removed from the DB.

For more information, see https://usetypo3.com/signals-and-hooks-in-typo3.html

Comment: First thank you for that, sounds good - but unforunately I'm getting some nasty `Fatal error: Call to a member function exec_SELECTgetSingleRow() on a non-object in ...\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Cache\Backend\Typo3DatabaseBackend.php on line 182` on Typo 6.2 just by adding the `$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager')->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher');` thing in my `ext_localconf.php`, even if the rest (connecting so a certain signal and the own class/method) is left out.

Comment: Of course I tried to clear caches, remove everything from typo3temp and deactivating / reactivating my plugin - always the same error; had a look at the referenced file / line but up to now I don't get behind what went wrong :-( - any idea?

Comment: See https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/208041/ :

Just use:

$signalSlotDispatcher =
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\SignalSlot\\Dispatcher');

Comment: At least in TYPO3 6.2, the "afterRemoveObject" signal doesn't seem to be emitted when deleting via the "List" backend. Though it does get emitted if you remove the object via the repository's `remove` method.