# Extbase Hooks - execute code upon record creation

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I want to create a standard typo3 extension but when I create a record (or modify it) I want to calculate something (in my case I want to call the Google Map API to get coordinates from a given address).

SO I search for a hook or something. Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean after creating a record from your extbase extension or any content record in the backend?

Comment: @TheF After creating a content record in the backend for my extension. (Like you create any content record, but just that record type for my extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my special case there was no need to calculate the coordinates when the record got saved. So I just used the listAction in the controller, check if coordinates are there and if not call the Google API (and send an email if the Google API does not give a coordinate back).

In another case where the new record comes from a frontend plugin and I had to do something with this data I used the createAction in the Controller. (I am not sure if the createAction is also called when the record is created from the backend.)

Answer (score 1):

One of my project example, may helps you for hook in backend when record has been changed.

> In your extension file ext_localconf.php

```
// Hook for cancellation
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = 'EXT:femanager/class.tx_femanager_tcemainprocdm.php:tx_femanager_tcemainprocdm';
```

> hook file class.tx_femanager_tcemainprocdm.php where you can execute
>   your script

```
class tx_femanager_tcemainprocdm{

    function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray ($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$reference){
        // $status also called action like delete
        // $table - table name of excute backend action
        // $id - record UID
        // $fieldArray - fields of your table

        if($table = 'your_extension_table_name'){
            // your script  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591992/typo3-extbase-individual-code-on-backend-deletion-of-an-object#answer-25600326) is useful to you.

Register your class as a [data handling hook](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_version_1_1_hook_1_1_data_handler_hook.html#ab753bdf58a8543ea194093e573e1abb0) in your extension. This one "is called AFTER all commands of the commandmap" were executed. Maybe you need to look for a more appropriate one.

Then in your registered Hook i.e. 'typo3conf/ext/your_ext/Classes/Hooks/AfterCreate.php' do your calculation. Hope this sets you on the right track.